# Two forms of chain rule in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

I am learning Complex analysis, and I have following questions:

I saw two forms of chain rules:

$$
(g \circ f)(a) = g'(f(a)) f'(a)
$$

$$
\frac{\partial g \circ f}{\partial z} = \left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial z} \circ f \right)\left(\frac{\partial f}{ \partial z}\right) +
\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial \bar z} \circ f \right)\left(\frac{\partial \bar f}{ \partial z}\right)
$$

We also know

$$
f'(a) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(a)
$$

Therefore I think

$$
(g \circ f)' = \frac{\partial (g \circ f)}{\partial z} =  g'(f(z)) f'(z) = \left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial z} \circ f \right)\left(\frac{\partial f}{ \partial z}\right)
$$

Doesn't this mean

$$
\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial \bar z} \circ f \right)\left(\frac{\partial \bar f}{ \partial z}\right)=0
$$

??

I am wondering where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If $f'$ exists, i.e $f$ is complex differentiable, then
$$f' = \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$$ and
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}} = 0$$
The first of your two forms is for those functions that are complex differentiable, and the second is for those that might not be.

Comment: thanks for your explanation!

Answer (score 0):

I write some detailed explanation about the difference between two forms of chain rule, and I am hopeful that this will be useful for others who see this post. Of course, the discussion I wrote here is not rigorous enough, and for more details, please refers to textbooks.

#### Pre-Definition

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = 1/2*(
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} - i \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}
) 
$$

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z} = 1/2 *(
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + i \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}
)
$$

#### Lemmas

##### (1)

Let $f,g$ be holomorphic, then $(g \circ  f)' = h' = (g'\circ f) \times f'$

###### Proof

$$
(g \circ  f)' = 
\frac{g(f(a +h)) - g(f(a))}{h}
=
\frac{g(f(a +h)) - g(f(a))}{f(a+h) -f(a)}
\times
\frac{f(a +h) - f(a)}{h}
$$

Because $g,f$ are holomorphic, they are continuoius and their derivative exist, thus terms above are all well defined and we have
$$
(g \circ  f)'  = (g'\circ f) \times f'
$$

##### (2)

If $f$ is holomorphic, then we have

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = f'
$$

###### Proof

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} - i \frac{ \partial f}{\partial y}\right)
$$

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \lim
\frac{f((a+h) +bi)- f(a+bi)}{h}
$$

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \lim
\frac{f(a +(b + h)i)- f(a+bi)}{h}
$$

Because $f$ is holomorphic, thus

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = -i \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = f'
$$

Thus

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = f'
$$

##### (3)

By (1), (2), we see if $f,g$ are holomorphic, we have

$$
\frac{\partial (g \circ f)}{\partial z} = h' = \left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial z} \circ f\right) \times \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}
$$

##### (4)

What if $f$ is not holomorphic, does $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$ still exists?

###### Discussion

Consider $f = |z|^2 = x^2 - y^2+2yi=u +vi$

$$
u_x' =2x, v_y'=2i, u_x' \not = v_y'
$$

Thus $f$ is not holomorphic

However

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 2x, \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = -2y+2i
$$

Thus $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$ is well defined

Therefore, we can say $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$ is an extention of the regular derivative definition

##### (5)

If $f,g$ may or may not be holomorphic, but both are differentiable on $x,y$-axis, compute

$$
\frac{\partial (g \circ f)}{\partial z}
$$

###### Computation

$$
\frac{\partial (g \circ f)}{\partial z}
= 
\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\partial (g \circ f)}{\partial x} -i 
\frac{\partial (g \circ f)}{\partial y}) 
$$

---

**X**

$$
\frac{\partial (g \circ f)}{\partial x}
=
\lim_h\frac{g(f(x + h + yi)) - g(f(x + yi))}{h}
$$

$$
= \lim_h\frac{g(f(x + h + yi)) - g(f(x + yi))}{f(x+h+yi) - f(x+yi)}
\times
\frac{f(x+h+yi) - f(x+yi)}{h}
$$

$$
= \lim_h G_x \times \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
$$

---

Let $\Delta = f(x+h+yi) - f(x+yi)$, and $w = f(x+yi)$

Then

$$
G_x = \frac{g(w + \Delta) - g(w)}{\Delta}
$$

Let $\Delta = \Delta_x + \Delta_y i$

Then we have

$$
\lim_\Delta g(w + \Delta) - g(w) = \lim_\Delta 
\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\Delta_x + \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\Delta_y
$$

---

$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial g}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial \bar z}
$$

$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} = i\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial g}{\partial \bar z}\right)
$$

---

$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\Delta_x + \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\Delta y = 
\Delta_x\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial \bar z}\right) +
i\Delta_y\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial g}{\partial \bar z}\right)
$$

$$
= \frac{\partial g}{\partial z}(\Delta_x + i\Delta_y)
+ \frac{\partial g}{\partial \bar z}(\Delta_x - i\Delta_y)
$$

$$
= \frac{\partial g}{\partial z}\Delta
+ \frac{\partial g}{\partial \bar z}\bar\Delta
$$

---

Then

$$
\lim_h G_x \times \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \lim
\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial z}\Delta(x) + \frac{\partial g}{\partial \bar z}\bar\Delta(x)\right) \frac{1}{\Delta(x)} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
$$

---

Similarity, we have
$$
\lim_h G_y \times \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \lim
\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial z}\Delta(y) + \frac{\partial g}{\partial \bar z}\bar\Delta(y)\right) \frac{1}{\Delta(y)} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}
$$

Notice that $\Delta(x) =\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} h_x$, $\Delta(y) =\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} h_y$, thus we have

$$
\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial z}\Delta(x) + \frac{\partial g}{\partial \bar z}\bar\Delta(x)\right) \frac{1}{\Delta(x)} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
= 
\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial z} \frac{\frac{\partial  f}{\partial x} h_x}{h_x} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial \bar z} \frac{\frac{\partial \bar f}{\partial x} h_x}{h_x}  \right) \frac{1}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
$$

$$
= \frac{\partial g}{\partial z} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+ \frac{\partial g}{\partial \bar z} \frac{\partial \bar f}{\partial x}
$$

---

$$
\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial z}\Delta(y) + \frac{\partial g}{\partial \bar z}\bar\Delta(y)\right) \frac{1}{\Delta(y)} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}
= 
\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial z} \frac{\frac{\partial  f}{\partial y} h_y}{h_y} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial \bar z} \frac{\frac{\partial \bar f}{\partial y} h_y}{h_y}  \right) \frac{1}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}
$$

$$
= \frac{\partial g}{\partial z} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}+ \frac{\partial g}{\partial \bar z} \frac{\partial \bar f}{\partial y}
$$

---

Finally

$$
\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{\partial g}{\partial z} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+ \frac{\partial g}{\partial \bar z} \frac{\partial \bar f}{\partial x} -i\left( \frac{\partial g}{\partial z} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}+ \frac{\partial g}{\partial \bar z} \frac{\partial \bar f}{\partial y}\right)\right]
$$

$$
=
\frac{1}{2}
[
\frac{\partial g}{\partial z} \left(\frac{ \partial f}{\partial x} - i \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)+ 
\frac{\partial g}{\partial \bar z}\left(\frac{\partial \bar f}{\partial x} - i \frac{\partial \bar f}{\partial y}\right)
] 
$$

$$
= \frac{\partial g}{\partial z}\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}
+ \frac{\partial g}{\partial \bar z} \frac{\partial \bar f}{\partial z}
$$